# How to add a shared classes JAR in Tomcat 9

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

I want to share some properties files and classes JARs between multiple webapps in Tomcat 9. I have created the folders "/opt/tomcat/shared/{classes,lib}" and placed my properties files into ".../classes" and JARs into ".../lib".

I have then edited "catalina.properties" and set the `shared.loader` to `shared.loader="/opt/tomcat/shared/classes","/opt/tomcat/shared/lib/*.jar"` as per the [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html). I have also seen this posted as the answer in a number of Stackoverflows.

The properties files seem to get picked-up OK, but I am getting `ClassNotFoundExeptions`s for classes in the JAR files. If I copy them into the `WEB-INF/lib` of the webapps, then things start to work (but for various reasons this is not a viable option).

It's not permissions, I have given 777 and 666 to the dirs & folders on GNU/Linux and also tried on Windows. The problem is the same.

What have I done wrong and what is the correct way to do this? The JARs **must** be picked up from an external folder due to reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was an issue with some other dependencies of the shared classes JARs that *were* in `WEB-INF/lib` and not `shared/lib`.

A quick reorganisation of locations to have `shared/dependencies` for those JAR files and things started to work.